# Matrix $p$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

> Suppose $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ and let the matrix $B$ be any submatrix of $A$. Show $\|B\|_p \leq \|A\|_p$.

We have that $$\|A\|_p = \max_{\|x\|_p = 1}\|Ax\|_p \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \|B\|_p = \max_{\|x\|_p = 1}\|Bx\|_p$$ Since $B$ is a submatrix of $A$ it seems obvious that $\|B\|_p \leq \|A\|_p$ but I am not sure how to show this is true rigorously. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We can find matrices $P$ and $Q$ for which $B = PAQ$ for which $\|P\|$ and $\|Q\|$ are $1$.  It follows that
$$
\|B\| = \|PAQ\| \leq \|P\|\,\|A\|\,\|Q\| = \|A\|
$$

---

For example, for a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$, we find that
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1} A \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0} = \pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{31}&a_{32}}
$$
In general: if $A$ is $m \times n$ the rows of $P$ are rows of the size-$m$ identity matrix, and the columns of $Q$ are columns of the size-$n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Unless I am missing something here it seems that the hint gives me the answer? or is there something else I need to show to prove the above statement?

Comment: Well, you have to figure out which matrices $P$ and $Q$ I'm referring to

Comment: I see how would one do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to respond to that comment. If you can figure out which $P$ and $Q$ correspond to a particular choice of submatrix, then you're all set.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how do we find matrices $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were stating that you knew how to do so.  I'll edit that in.

Comment: So, we have our $P$ and $Q$ now so to finish the above question we just need to state what you wrote down in your answer correct or is there more to it then that?

Comment: Well, you have to state that it's possible to do that no matter which submatrix you consider

Comment: Could you look at the other questions I posted for lower triangular $L$?