# An induced matrix norm equal to the matrix $\infty$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

> Suppose $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$. Consider the matrix norm $\|A\|$ induced by two vector $\infty$-norms $\|x\|_{\infty}$ and $\|y\|_{\infty}$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{C}^m$ respectively, $$\|A\| = \max_{\|x\|_{\infty} = 1}\|Ax\|_{\infty}$$ Is this induced norm the same as the matrix $\infty$-norm defined by $$\|A\|_{\infty} = \max_{1\leq i\leq m}\|e_i^H A\|_{1}$$ If so prove it.

I want to know to know what $e_i^H A$ means does the mean I am taking the $i$-th rows of $A$ or the $i$-th columns of $A$? Just need some basic understandings of what I have here, pretty rusty on linear algebra.

Is there another way of writing the induced matrix norm perhaps $$\|A\| = \|x\|_{1}\|A\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: In the title you ask about equivalence. In the Q you ak if they are the same. $\mathbb C^{m\times n}$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. All norms on a finite-dimensional real or complex vector space are equivalent, in that they induce the same topology.

Comment: edited the title of the question

Comment: $e_i^H A$ is the $i$th row of $A$, just as $Ae_j$ is the $j$th column of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ok, got it. So then would $Ae_i$ be the $i$th column of $A$ just want to know how these can be varied and there meanings.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to note that $e_i^H A = (A^H e_i)^H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is yes.  In order to prove it, note that
$$
\|Ax\|_\infty = \left \| \pmatrix{(e_1^H A)x\\ \vdots \\ (e_m^H A)x} \right\|_\infty = \max_{i=1,\dots,m} \left|(e_i^H A)x\right| \leq \\ \max_{i=1,\dots m } \|(e_i^H A)\|_1 \cdot \|x\|_\infty
$$
The inequality comes from the general result $|u^Tv| \leq \|u\|_1 \|v\|_\infty$, which you may consider as an instance of Hölder's inequality.  In any case, the proof of the inequality is pretty quick (but it requires expanding the dot-product as a sum, which I'm too lazy to do).

From there, it is necessary to show that this upper bound is attained.  That is, it is necessary to find an $x$ with $\|x\|_\infty = 1$ and $\|Ax\|_\infty = \|A\|_\infty$. To that effect, let $i$ be the row of $A$ with the highest $1$-norm, and consider $x$ to be given by
$$
x_j = \frac{|e_iAe_j|}{e_iAe_j} = \frac{|A_{ij}|}{A_{ij}} \quad j = 1,\dots,n
$$
(in the case that $A_{ij} = 0$, set $x_j = 1$).

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to show that the inequality holds true since it is a result of Hoelder. But, once we have this inequality I am a tad confused where to go from there from what you have.

Comment: If you plug the inequality into the definition of $\|A\|$, you can now verify that $\|A\| \leq \max_{1 \leq i\leq m} \cdots$.  However, that on its own does not complete the proof, hence the second part.

Comment: Right, so after the inequality I am confused about your second part. As in we have to find an $x$ such that $\|x\|_{\infty} = 1$ to show that $\|A\| = \|A\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: In the first part, we showed that 
$$
\|A\|_\infty = \max_{\|x\|_\infty = 1}\|Ax\|_\infty \leq 
\max_{\|x\|_\infty = 1}\left(  \max_{i=1,\dots m } \|(e_i^H A)\|_1 \cdot \|x\|_\infty\right) = \max_{i=1,\dots m } \|(e_i^H A)\|_1
$$
That is, we have shown that
$$
\|A\|_\infty \leq \max_{i=1,\dots m } \|(e_i^H A)\|_1
$$ 
We have yet to show, however, that 
$$
\|A\|_\infty \geq \max_{i=1,\dots m } \|(e_i^H A)\|_1
$$

Comment: Ok, hmm I don't understand your solution then. Any idea how I can do this on my own?

Comment: I'm not sure what part you don't understand, so I'm not sure what to tell you.  This is one of those problems for which there's only one reasonable solution, however you happen to arrive at it and express it.  Perhaps it will be helpful for you to write everything out in summation notation and try to reach the first inequality in the comment above.

Comment: Nevermind it clicked I think I got it now, for the first inequality do you have any recommendations on showing that $\|A\|_{\infty} \geq \max_{i=1,\ldots,m}\|e_i^{H}A\|_{1}$?

Comment: @Wolfy yes, choose the right vector $x$ with $\|x\|_\infty = 1$.  In fact, that's exactly what I'm doing in the second part.